# Changes made to docker image via terminal do not save?

Tags: bash, docker, terminal

I am able to run the following command and have my terminal open up a bash terminal where in which I can interact with my docker image:

```
sudo docker run -i -t c5d3c4c383d1 /bin/bash
```

The trouble is when I make changes to this docker image in the bash terminal, and then exit the image, the changes to the image do not save.

How can I make it so the changes I make in the bash terminal persist for the image?

Comment: You should read on the difference between a docker image and a docker container

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best way would be to run your image with a [bind mount](https://docs.docker.com/engine/admin/volumes/bind-mounts/) or (better) [a volume](https://docs.docker.com/engine/admin/volumes/volumes/): that way, the modification done during the sesssion, if done in the right (mounted) path, would persists.

If not, in your current case, you would need to [`docker commit`](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/commit/) your stopped container into an image in order to preserve your current session.

[image: https://docs.docker.com/engine/admin/volumes/images/types-of-mounts-volume.png]